# Sort an array in a for loop and fill a new array with the sorted values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, loops

I have an array, `$items`, which contains lot of informations:
name, size, quantity, color, id...
I'm using 'for' loops to sort `$items` values by color and save the sorted values in a new array, But the values I get in the generated array are false or not right ordered.

In the way to sort `$items`, I first created 3 arrays from $items

```
    <?php
    $total = $item_number; // total count of $items iterations
    $color_list_final = array_values(array_unique($color_list)); // color list without occurrences
    $name_list_final = array_values(array_unique($name_list)); // name list without occurrences
    ?>
```

Then used them as reference to compare to `$item`

```
    <?php
    echo 'TEST - 1 - SORT BY COLORS<br/>';

    $sorted_items = array();  // the new array to fill
    $count_sorting = array(); // will count the total of all iterations

    // SORT BY COLORS
    $countfrom0 = -1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $color_list_count; $i++) 
    {
        $countfrom0++;
        $current_color = $color_list_final[$countfrom0];

        echo 'couleur :'.$i.' '.$current_color.'<br/>';

        //SAVING THE CURRENT COLOR GROUP VALUE IN THE NEW ARRAY
        $sorted_items[$i]['color'] = $current_color;

        $i3 = 0;
        for ($i2 = 0; $i2 <= $total; $i2++) 
        {
            //IF ITEM HAVE THE SAME COLOR THAN THE CURRENT COLOR
            if($item[$i2]['color'] == $color_list_final[$countfrom0])
            {
                echo trim($item[$i2]['name']).' - '.$item[$i2]['size'].' - '.$item[$i2]['color'].'<br/>';

                //SAVING THE ITEMS VALUES IN THE NEW ARRAY
                $line[$i3] = trim($item[$i2]['name']).' - '.$item[$i2]['size'].' - '.$item[$i2]['color'].'<br/>';
                $sorted_items[$i]['items'] = $line;

                $count_sorting[$i3] = $i3;

                $i3++;
             }
        }
        echo '---------------------------<br/>';    
    }
    echo '<br/>';
?>
```

So echo are displaying the structure that I wanted

```
    COULEUR :0  #A0C343
    FREE BEES -  XL -  #A0C343
    FREE BEES -  M -  #A0C343
    COLOMBUS -  XS -  #A0C343
    FREE BEES -  XXXL -  #A0C343
    ---------------------------
    COULEUR :1  #FFE673
    FREE BEES -  M -  #FFE673
    ---------------------------
    COULEUR :2  #F7D8D3
    COLOMBUS -  XS -  #F7D8D3
    COLOMBUS -  S -  #F7D8D3
    ---------------------------
```

Now, when I'm doing a print_r on `$sorted_items`, I get the right number of array by color (3), but the nested array `$line` seems to keep the size and values of his first passage, and then, for the others passages, it replace the old values by the new ones who have the same index... but old values who'll have a bigger index than the new values, will remain the same as for the first passage.

```
ARRAY
(
[0] => ARRAY
    (
        [COLOR] =>  #A0C343
        [ITEMS] => ARRAY
            (
                [0] => FREE BEES -  XL -  #A0C343
                [1] => FREE BEES -  M -  #A0C343
                [2] => COLOMBUS -  XS -  #A0C343
                [3] => FREE BEES -  XXXL -  #A0C343
            )

    )

[1] => ARRAY
    (
        [COLOR] =>  #FFE673
        [ITEMS] => ARRAY
            (
                [0] => FREE BEES -  M -  #FFE673
                [1] => FREE BEES -  M -  #A0C343
                [2] => COLOMBUS -  XS -  #A0C343
                [3] => FREE BEES -  XXXL -  #A0C343
            )

    )

[2] => ARRAY
    (
        [COLOR] =>  #F7D8D3
        [ITEMS] => ARRAY
            (
                [0] => COLOMBUS -  XS -  #F7D8D3
                [1] => COLOMBUS -  S -  #F7D8D3
                [2] => COLOMBUS -  XS -  #A0C343
                [3] => FREE BEES -  XXXL -  #A0C343
            )

    )

)
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I emptied the array ‘$line‘ after the nested ‘for‘ loop

```
$i3 = 0;
for ($i2 = 0; $i2 <= $total; $i2++) 
{
    //SI LA COULEUR DE L ITEM EST LA MM QUE CELLE PRECEDEMENT DEFINI
    if($item[$i2]['color'] == $color_list_final[$countfrom0])
    {
        echo trim($item[$i2]['name']).' - '.$item[$i2]['size'].' - '.$item[$i2]['color'].'<br/>';

        $line[$i3] = trim($item[$i2]['name']).' - '.$item[$i2]['size'].' - '.$item[$i2]['color'];
        $sorted_items[$i]['items'] = $line;

        $count_sorting[$i3] = $i3;

        $i3++;
    }
}
$line = array();
```

And it gives me exactly what I wanted

```
ARRAY
(
[0] => ARRAY
    (
        [COLOR] =>  #A0C343
        [ITEMS] => ARRAY
            (
                [0] => FREE BEES -  XL -  #A0C343
                [1] => FREE BEES -  M -  #A0C343
                [2] => COLOMBUS -  XS -  #A0C343
                [3] => FREE BEES -  XXXL -  #A0C343
            )

    )

[1] => ARRAY
    (
        [COLOR] =>  #FFE673
        [ITEMS] => ARRAY
            (
                [0] => FREE BEES -  M -  #FFE673
            )

    )

[2] => ARRAY
    (
        [COLOR] =>  #F7D8D3
        [ITEMS] => ARRAY
            (
                [0] => COLOMBUS -  XS -  #F7D8D3
                [1] => COLOMBUS -  S -  #F7D8D3
            )

    )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

if it is `echo`ing in the right order then try to populate an array with the data at the point where you `echo` it. this is quite a long thread to debug without using the code itself, but perhaps you could try to turn

```
echo trim($item[$i2]['name']).' - '.$item[$i2]['size'].' - '.$item[$i2]['color'].'<br/>';
```

into

```
$array[$i2] = array(  'name'  => trim($item[$i2]['name'])
                   ,  'item'   => $item[$i2]['size']
                   ,  'color' => $item[$i2]['color']
                   );
```

also, `$i3`'s role seems a little ambiguous so maybe either declare it in a `for()` loop or get rid of it altogether.

Comment: First thanks you for your answer, and then sorry for the delay!

Comment: `$i3` counter needs to be incremented only if the `if` condition is true, that's why I set it alone.
I tried your suggestion with some modification and it worked in a certain way (I'll edit my post in few minutes), but the array `$line` seems to keep the size and values of his first passage, and then, for the others passages, it replace the old values by the new ones who have the same index... but old values who'll have a bigger index than the new values, will remain the same as for the first passage.